# Dismissal completion callback is executed after custom view controller transition is cancelled

Tags: ios

I'm trying to build a custom view controller transition which is interactive and interruptible with these APIs:

- UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning
- UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition
- UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate
- UIViewPropertyAnimator

What I want to achieve is that I can present a view controller modally, and then use `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to dismiss the presented view controller by dragging it downward. If I release my finger in the upper half of the screen, the transition should be cancelled, otherwise the transition will be completed successfully.

Here is the code about the problem:

```swift
    func handlePanGesture(gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: presentedViewController.view)
        switch gestureRecognizer.state {
        case .began:
            interacting = true
            presentingViewController.dismiss(animated: true) {
                print("Dismissal Completion Callback is Called.")
                // How can I know the dismissal is successful or cancelled.
            }
        case .changed:
            let fraction = (translation.y / UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
            update(fraction)
        case .ended, .cancelled:
            interacting = false
            if (percentComplete > 0.5) {
                finish()
            } else {
                cancel()
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

My code works great on the aspect of UI and interaction, but I don't understand the behavior of function `func dismiss(animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil)`.

In the `.began` case of `Pan Gesture`, `presentingViewController.dismiss(animated: true) { ... }` is called, so the custom transition starts. But the `completion` callback is always called no mater the dismissal transition is cancelled or not.

I watched these videos of WWDC:

- [Custom Transitions Using View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/218)
- [Advances in UIKit Animations and Transitions](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/216/?time=1627)

[image]

They use an example code to demonstrate custom transition with UINavigationController and do not mention the dismissal callback.

```swift
presentingViewController.dismiss(animated: true) {
        debugPrint("Dismissal Completion Called")
        debugPrint("[ presentedViewController.transitionCoordinator?.isCancelled \(self.presentedViewController.transitionCoordinator?.isCancelled) ]")
}
```

In the document about the `completion` parameter:

> completion
>
> The block to execute after the view controller is dismissed. This block has no return value and takes no parameters. You may specify nil for this parameter.

#### The Question

What is the real meaning of `Completion` since it is always called after custom transition is cancelled or finished ？

When I use custom transition with presentation and dismissal, what's best practice of handling the real dismissal completion to update UI and data ？

Answer (score 0):

After a little research and testing -- yeah, I'd say this is a bit confusing.

The completion block is **NOT** called after the VC has been dismissed. Rather, it is called ***after the function returns***.

So, assuming you are implementing `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition`, `.dismiss()` triggers your transition code, and returns when you `cancel()` or `finish()` -- but its completion block has no knowledge of what you actually did with the transition.

I'm sure there are a various approaches to this... but my first thought would be to put your "completion code" in `case .ended, .cancelled:` where you are (already) determining whether or not to remove the VC (whether to call `.cancel()` or `.finish()`).

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I find something helpful in the document of Apple:

> At the end of a transition animation, it is critical that you call the `completeTransition:` method. Calling that method tells UIKit that the transition is complete and that the user may begin to use the presented view controller. Calling that method also triggers a cascade of other completion handlers, including the one from the presentViewController:animated:completion: method and the animator object’s own animationEnded: method. The best place to call the completeTransition: method is in the completion handler of your animation block.
>
> Because transitions can be canceled, you should use the return value of the transitionWasCancelled method of the context object to determine what cleanup is required. When a presentation is canceled, your animator must undo any modifications it made to the view hierarchy. A successful dismissal requires similar actions.

So the completion callback of `present(_:animated:completion:)` and `dismiss(animated:completion:)` do not have any parameters to indicate whether the transition is finished or cancelled. They are both called if the `transitionContext.completeTransition(_:)` method is called while transition is finished or cancelled. Such behavior is deliberately designed.